# Call a JavaScript function after an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with executing a JavaScript function after an Ajax request with JQuery.

First, I call a PHP page with an Ajax request, everything works fine.

In this PHP page, I return a JavaScript call for a function.

But when I append this script on my HTML page, Firebug return this : `"ReferenceError: getNumber is not defined" getNumber(55);`. (55 is just an example, it can be from 0 to 100)

**HTML** (Jquery and myScript are loaded correctly):

```
<script src="jquery1111min.js"></script>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
<div id="content_modal" class="content_modal">

</div>
```

**JQuery** (myScript.js):

```
$.get("inc/get_something.php", function(data) {
  $(".content_modal").html(data);//Works
});
function getNumber(nb) {
  alert(nb);//never called
}
```

**PHP** (get_something.php):

```
//some html
$number = mt_rand(0,100);
<script>getNumber(<?=$number?>);</script>
```

Cheers

Comment: getNumber must be in a closure, like dom ready or something.... and it shouldn't if you want it to work.

Comment: just return the number itself as the output then call `getNumber` with the random number from PHP in your success callback.  to execute the JavaScript you send back here you will have to utilize `eval` ([which is evil](http://stackoverflow.com/q/197769/697370))

Comment: I return other things than the <script>, there is some HTML too

Comment: Press F12, are you seeing any errors when this ajax request occurs in the console?

Comment: console error is : "ReferenceError: getNumber is not defined" getNumber(55);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your

```
function getNumber(nb) { ... }
```

oustide your

```
$(document).ready()
```

or

```
$(window).load()
```

If not, try putting it outside anything, in top of your  tag

Comment: It was that ! Thanks you :)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot execute javascript from a php page that isn't rendered in the browser. JavaScript is rendered in the browser and not on the server.

Comment: he isn't trying to execute javascript from php, he's returning html that contains a script tag and some javascript code that is to be parsed and executed by the browser.

Comment: @KevinB You understand what I want to do perfectly :)